# Typing Dots animation before a message pops up

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am working on a landing page for which I have created a loading dots animation. When the page loads, some messages randomly pop up on the page. I want these dots to appear every time before a new message appears. So far I have been able to show this animation only once when the page loads for the first time.
Below is the glimpse of my code:
**HTML**

```
<div id=Container> 
    <div id="messageContainer">
            <button id="Text">
                <span>o</span>
                <span>o</span>
                <span>o</span>
            </>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for Animation**

```
#messageContainer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
}

.newButton {
    
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(96.04deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    font-family: Poppins;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#Text {
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(96.04deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: .2;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: .2;
    }
}

#Text span {
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#Text span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: .2s;
}

#Text span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: .4s;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function firstButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.className = 'newButton';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Hey';

    document.getElementById('messageContainer').appendChild(btn);
}

function secondButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.className = 'newButton';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Pssst';

    document.getElementById('messageContainer').appendChild(btn);
}

function thirdButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.className = 'newButton';
    btn.innerHTML = 'How have you been here?';

    document.getElementById('messageContainer').appendChild(btn);
}

function fourthButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.className = 'newButton';
    btn.innerHTML = 'I have got something to show you';

    document.getElementById('messageContainer').appendChild(btn);
}

function fifthButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.className = 'newButton';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Wanna See?';

    document.getElementById('messageContainer').appendChild(btn);
}

setTimeout(() => {
    firstButton();
}, 3000);

setTimeout(() => {
    secondButton();
}, 5000);

setTimeout(() => {
    thirdButton();
}, 7000);

setTimeout(() => {
    fourthButton();
}, 10000);

setTimeout(() => {
    fifthButton();
}, 12000);

function hideDots() {
    document.getElementById('Text').style.display = "none";
}



setTimeout(() => {
    hideDots();
}, 2500);
```

Here's the link to my JS Fiddle code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Ghazi360/nbr2w9ze/8/

I have created different functions for each new message & used setTimeOut function to put gap of some seconds before a new message appears. Instead of that empty time gap, I want to put the Dots Animation there. I hope I am able to explain what I want. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then instantly showing the dots when the page loads, showing and hiding the dots should be part of the flow for displaying each message.

You could keep your messages in an array and iterate over them, for each message doing the following:

```
Show Dots (x ms duration) -> Hide Dots -> Show Message Text
```

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjvf8mqe/14/) for this based on your initial fiddle.